# Did the US government profit from any of the military hardware they gave to the Afghan government?

Tags: united-states, military, afghanistan

The US government gave a lot of military aid to the Afghan government and even helped them maintain many of the equipment through western contractors. Did they ever get the full or partial price for any of the tanks, hardware, fighter planes or was it all given to the Afghan army as aid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the West subsidized the Afghan government, any payment would have been an accounting fiction. Something like [half the government budget](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/DT.ODA.ODAT.XP.ZS?end=2019&locations=AF&start=1960&view=chart) was aid in recent years. Afghanistan had several billion dollars [trade deficit](https://www.statista.com/statistics/262186/afghanistans-trade-balance/) per year. So any money the Afghans might have had to pay could not have been earned in-country.

The US government "profiting" is a strange way to look at it. The US taxpayer paid the DoD to give equipment to the Afghan army, so the DoD purchased it from defense industries (many of the American), so those industries made profits which got taxed -- to some degree -- in the US.

The Afghan air force had no fighters, by the way. They had transport and ground attack planes and helicopters. I'm not aware of any tanks, either, unless they kept some Soviet relics running.

Comment: It seems to make sense that the Afghan air force had no tanks. An air force needs ground defenses to protect their operations. Tanks seem to be more of an offensive division, not one protecting the current deployment.

Comment: @doneal24, I'm not aware of any new tanks in the Afghan **army**. Unlike, say, Iraq or Egypt or other recipients of US aid.